# jQuery How to add a portlet

Tags: jquery-ui, portlet

How do I add an jQuery UI Portlet to an existing set of Portlets?

(Check: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/portlets.html)

How to add a portlet after loading?

In my personal project I implemented portlets: http://www.soliman.nl/test/jqueryui/ui_2.php
 and I would like to make a button to append a portlet. I tried appending it to .column, but the CSS is not loaded(of course), when you .addClass, all other portlets are affected too. There must be a simple way...but how?

Comment: What exactly happens when you `.addClass`? Could you uncomment that on your page so we can witness the error? (When I execute the code after the new div has been added, the other portlets are not affected.) Great comments, by the way, only the first is a bit harsh.

Comment: Hi. All other portlets get a minus (-) symbol for minimizing.

Comment: Thanks for the complement, forgot about the first one :). Removed comment stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're doing

```
$(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
.find(".portlet-header")
.addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
.prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
.end()
.find(".portlet-content");
```

What if you get rid of the `$(".portlet")` and keep using the `$(".addspace")` you had *before the replaceWith*, like this?

```
$('.addspace').replaceWith(html)
.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
.find(".portlet-header")
.addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
.prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
.end()
.find(".portlet-content");
```

Comment: But now your portlet is stuck in the addspace. You won't be able to add a second one...

Comment: Solved. First replace, then addClass.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a few portlets, add last div with class addspace.

Then create a function with .replaceWith and a .addClass.

```
$('.addspace').replaceWith(html);
```

Example of returned HTML:

```
<div class="portlet" id="portletname"> <!-- make sure portletname is unique -->
<div class="portlet-header">test</div>
<div class="portlet-content">test</div>
</div>

<!-- New addspace (replaceWith replaces the old one)  -->
<div class="addspace" >
</div
```

Add portlet class to div by id:

```
$('#portletname')
      .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
      .find(".portlet-header")
      .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
      .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
      .end()
      .find(".portlet-content");
```